# Image Masking+Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I want to mask two images

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Now i want to merge this two images like The image2 will come in centre of the image1.

I've read [Any idea why this image masking code does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133248/any-idea-why-this-image-masking-code-does-not-work) and ["How to Mask an Image"](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html)

But on using this function:-

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;     
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```

But by using this function I got the output is :-

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: good question @shweta, keep it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the problem is not with `maskImage:withMask:`. The wrong output you posted is not wrong: where the pixels of image1 are black, image2 is not visible.

The problem is probably or in the functions you used to load `image` and `mask`, or in the code producing the graphical output.
Actually it seems to me that you got the right output, but using the wrong colorspace (grayscale without alpha). Check if the argument `image` you supply is actually in RGBa format, and if the returned `UIImage` isn't drawn onto some other `CGContext` using DeviceGray as colorspace.

The other possible cause that comes to my mind is that you inverted image1 and image2. According to the documentation, `mask` should be scaled up to the size of `image` (see below) but you have a small image there. This seems reasonable also because image1 is in grayscale, although when I tried to swap image1 and image2 I got image1 unmodified as output.

---

To run the tests I used the images attached, and then copied & pasted the method `-(UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage` as it is.

I used a simple iOS project with one view and an `UIImageView` inside (with tag 1), and the following code in the controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

    UIImage *im1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
    UIImage *im2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];

    imageView.image=[self maskImage:im2 withMask:im1];

}
```

I get the following output (which is right):

[image: image2 using image1 as mask]

If by mistake you invert im1 with im2, you get instead image1 unmodified.